# Best Practices for rotating syslog logs on RHEL with different schedules?

Tags: linux, redhat, syslog, best-practices

OS:
Running RHEL 5.6.

Situation:
I need to rotate /var/log/messagees on a different schedule than the rest of the syslog logs.

By default syslog logs are rotated weekly based on the /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/syslog configuration files.

If you look at /etc/logrotate.d/syslog you will find that there is one logrotate configuration block for all of the logs.  If I want /var/log/messages to rotate on a different schedule I need to create a separate configuration block for it.  This would result in restarting syslogd twice (based on copying the existing config).

Question: 
Is there a way to rotate /var/log/messages on a different schedule than the other syslog logs without having to send HUP to syslogd twice?  Or does this even matter?  What is the best practice here?

Comment: I believe the only thing HUP signal does it tell syslog to close, and re-open the log files.  I can't imagine this would be a huge problem unless you an extremely active system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a separate block for the messages log in /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog (or whatever it's called on your install).  It should use the setting for the  specific log file match preferentially to a general one.

No, as Zoredache mentioned, multiple HUPs shouldn't break anything unless you're really hammering rsyslog anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys, the system is not too busy.  I will impalement this.  I couldn't think of a reason not to, wanted to see if anyone saw any negatives in doing things this way.

Comment: If you think the answer fits your question, please make sure you accept and/or upvote the answers. You're more likely to get folks to answer your future questions if you have a high percentage of accepted answers.